# How do you select text on IE desktop with touch gestures?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, touchscreen

When using IE10 or IE11 in desktop mode, how do you select text using touch gestures?

Double tap zooms in; tap-and-hold is the equivalent of right-clicking at that pointer location.

Is text selection with touch gestures supported at all on IE10/IE11 desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows 8.1, just tap a word and it will be selected and then you can use the grippers to expand the selection.

Answer (score 1):

I've only watched somebody doing this, not having done it myself, but I believe you need to tap on or near the text and use popup controls to select the text.